# Missing Controls in page after timer method ticks

Tags: asp.net, timer, request.form

I have some code that handles a timer method, that just updates a label and changes it to a last updated at this time.

```
Protected Sub specialNotesTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles specialNotesTimer.Tick
    Label1.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
End Sub
```

When it ticks however, any other control on the page cannot be found via a button press. Image buttons or my other dynamically created controls, w.e the case, are missing.
I have a function that finds the fired control on the page, then returns the control so I can determine what to do

```
Public Shared Function GetPostBackControl(ByVal thePage As Page) As Control
    Dim myControl As Control = Nothing
    Dim ctrlName As String = thePage.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET")
    If ((ctrlName IsNot Nothing) And (ctrlName <> String.Empty)) Then
        myControl = thePage.FindControl(ctrlName)
    Else
        For Each Item As String In thePage.Request.Form
            Dim c As Control = thePage.FindControl(Item)
            If (TypeOf (c) Is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button) Then
                 myControl = c
            End If
        Next

    End If
    Return myControl
End Function
```

This works before the timer.tick, but not after. The control won't be listed as an Item in thePage.Request.Form, and it'll throw a null exception, when I know the control is there.

Comment: What is the purpose of outputting the datetime? is an action actually taking place or are you simply just outputting a datetime every X seconds? If the latter is true you may want to use Jquery instead to avoid losing your dynamic controls.

Comment: The purpose is just debugging to make sure the timer.tick is firing off. It's going to get replaced with and sql statement later, once I get this working.

Comment: You will have to create a method that builds all your dynamic controls, then call it every time the timer is fired, otherwise as you stated above all your controls will go missing. I'm assuming this is all wrapped in a updatepanel correct?

Comment: The timer itself is in an update panel, as well as the label. The image button is in a seperate update panel, that creates it's own dynamic controls in it's own update panel.

Comment: Also to add, it's not even dynamic controls that wont fire after the .tick. It's any button. Static image buttons on the page will not fire either.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if you are losing your event wiring - have you tried rewiring your click events in the tick to see if that could be the cause? I'm trying to recreate the code here to see if I can see/test it locally as well.